# Electrical resistance across the diagonal of a square metal plate

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

According to [Thévenin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem), any graph built from wires with specified resistances and possessing a distinguished source and sink will be "equivalent" to a single resistor connecting the source to the sink.

1. What is the best mathematical generalization of Thévenin's theorem?  Given a positive smooth function on a Riemannian manifold (which gives the resistance at every point), is there a nice operator which measures the resistance between a pair of points?
2. Given a square metal plate of uniform resistance, how can I compute the measured resistance from one corner to its opposite?

Comment: Following Denis Serre's answer, the problem seems to be that the fundamental solution to the Laplacian is locally unbounded in dimension greater than 1.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to Question 2: this resistance is infinite. In a vicinity of one corner, any (quarter of) corona delimited by the circles of radii $r$ and $r+\delta r$ has a resistance proportional to $\delta r$ and to the inverse $\frac2{\pi r}$ of its width. Thus the overall resistance involves the integral
$$\int_0\frac{dr}r,$$
which diverges.

The answer to Question 1 is essentially the same. The problem is that a point has an infinite capacity: There does not exist a solution of $\Delta V=0$ in a punctered domain $\Omega\setminus(P,Q)$ such that $V(P)=+1$, $V(Q)=-1$ and $V\equiv0$ along $\partial\Omega$. Actually, points are removable singularities in planar domains: suppose that $\Delta f=0$ in $\Omega\setminus(P)$, and that $f$ has a finite "electric energy", which is Dirchlet integral here,
$$\int_{\Omega\setminus P}|\nabla f|^2dx<+\infty.$$
Then $f$ extends as a harmonic function in $\Omega$. In particular, the potential $V$ considered above should be harmonic in $\Omega$; then because of the boundary condition and the maximum principle, one should have $V\equiv0$, which contradicts the values at $P$ and $Q$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can have something as fancy as Thévenin's theorem in a general Riemannian manifold, but as a physicist I'd say you'd be better off looking at generalizations of the conductivity, $\sigma=1/\rho$, where $\rho$ is the resistivity and can be measured as $\rho=R A/L$ for a (homogeneous) wire of cross-section $A$, length $L$, and resistance $R$. Then you can formulate a local version of Ohm's law as $$\mathbf{j}=\sigma\mathbf{E},$$ where $\mathbf{j}$ is the current density, related to the current $I$ flowing through a surface $\Sigma$ as $I=\int_\Sigma \mathbf{j}\cdot\textrm{d}\mathbf{A}$, and $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field, related to the potential difference $V(\mathbf{x})-V(\mathbf{y})$  between arbitrary points $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} $ as the line integral $\Delta V=\int_{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{y}} \mathbf{E}\cdot\textrm{d}\mathbf{r}$ (independent of the integration path).

As for the second question, you'd have to solve Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 V=0$ on a rectangular-box domain $[0,L]\times[0,L]\times[0,h]$, with appropriate boundary conditions - I'm not that sure there, but I'd set $V=0$ on $(0,0,z)$ and $V=V_0$ on $(L,L,z)$ to begin with; if that does not determine a unique solution then Neumann conditions on the rest of the boundary should do it. You then find the electric field $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla V$ to get the current density and integrate across an appropriate spanning surface, say the other diagonal plane.

I'll try and flesh this out and fill this in when I have time.

EDIT
J. Cserti's paper Application of the lattice Green's function for calculating the resistance of an infinite networks of resistors, *Am. J. Phys.* **68** no. 10, pp 896 (2000), [doi:10.1119/1.1285881](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.1285881), [arXiv:cond-mat/9909120](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9909120), solves the discretized problem of an infinite network of resistors on a square grid (including as a special case [the Nerd Sniping xkcd problem](http://xkcd.com/356/)). In the continuum limit that yields a solution to this problem.